# How do I stop Access from silently truncating Short Text fields when inserting records?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple, single user database, I am working with inside of the Microsoft 365 Access app. I am trying to use queries to pull a subset of data from one table (which was an imported .csv, but that isn't relevant to the issue) into another. I want to use the Field Size property on the **Short Text** fields to passively make sure junk doesn't end up in my database, since my source data is hundreds of thousands of records and not guaranteed to be perfectly clean.

I had assumed that if the source data contained more characters in a field than were allowed in the target field, it would trigger the "Microsoft Access can't append all the records in the append query." message. I could then abort the query and go track down the problem data if such a thing ever happened. I thought it wise to double check and, to my horror, no such message appeared. When I looked at the resulting data, the fields had been truncated at their respective character limits.

The following queries replicate the issue, but it happens whether I use the SQL view or the Design view, and whether just one record is inserted like this or a bunch of records are selected from another table.

```
CREATE TABLE myFirstTable
(
  id INT NOT NULL,
  tenCharacters VARCHAR(10),
  maxCharacters VARCHAR,
  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

```
INSERT INTO myFirstTable (id, tenCharacters, maxCharacters)
SELECT 1, "going to be cut short", "this can be as long as I want, up to 255 characters"
```

**Is there any way to get Access to stop silently truncating my Short Text fields?** Any kind of error message or chance to abort would be good enough to let me know something went wrong and I should inspect the selection getting appended more carefully.

I've checked all the Access SQL documentation I can find, and cannot find any mention of this scenario. All my googling has failed me because if anyone else had this problem with **Short Text** they have been drowned out by the many, *many* instances of people asking about Access or SQL Server truncating **Long Text/Memo** fields at 255 characters in a whole slew of different circumstances.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628140) implies that SQL Server sometimes throws an error in this scenario, so it feels like it is a reasonable thing to want.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855921) to a different question seems to suggest ANSI_WARNINGS are related, but I am not familiar with Ruby or SQL Server so I don't fully understand the answer, and couldn't find a similarly named setting in Access.

I have been writing my queries in the SQL View of the query builder, since some of the other things I've needed to do were a bit beyond what the Design View can handle. I haven't needed to use VBA for anything, and the smaller scope of this project means the time investment / learning curve is not really worth it, so I'd like to continue avoiding it if there's another way to deal with this.

Comment: I think your research has revealed the answer is "no".

Comment: just in case, Just validate the data in a separate step.  For instance load the data into a loading table.  Then run queries to validate the data before moving the data into the appropriate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Be proactive - filter for the records that would/should fail:

```sql
Select * From YourSourceTable
Where Len([YourLimitingField]) > 255
```

Then correct these as needed before appending to the destination table.